# Redirecting webpage in ASP.NET depending on the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

I've a domain name called mywebsite.com but I prefer users to access to my website through the www subdomain.

How can I achieve a verification and redirection in asp.net mvc3 easily?

When I was using php I did something like that :

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "www.mywebsite.com")
     header('Location: www.mywebsite.com');
```

I'd like to find a similar way to achieve this kind of redirection in asp.net (C#) (I'd prefer not to set a 301 redirection but just a soft redirection like the one I was using in PHP).

I know I could do a verification in each of my controllers action methods and the redirect the user if he is not on the subdomain www.mywebsite.com but I'd prefer to write once the verification and the redirection and I can't find where :/

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
Request.Url.ToString()
```

This will return the URL , then you can quickly check if it contains 'www.' and redirect if true. However I would suggest that your handle this in the URL rewrite in IIS.

Follow the guide here: http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2011/08/iis-7-redirect-domaincom-to.html this is for making domain.com go to www.domain.com, but it works the same way for the opposite.

Comment: I'll try to access the IIS through IIS manager because I've a shared windows hosting but normally it will be ok, thanks :)

Comment: You could ask your host to perform this for you if it ins't available thorough a panel, they will do it as it's a pretty basic thing :)

Comment: I've setted it through the IIS Manager - Url Rewrite module. There was an assistant to create a new rule, I just have to select the main domain and it is redirecting the other one on it !
It works perfectly <3

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this

```
 if(!Request.Url.Host.Equals("www.mywebsite.com"))
 {
      Response.Redirect("website");
 }
```

Comment: I know I can verify the host in this way, but where could I put the code? I don't want to copy/past or call a method in every action method of all of my controllers :/

Comment: put it in your master's page load

Comment: I don't have a master page because I'm doing a MVC3 asp.net application. Thus I only have shared views instead of a master page :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the original question asks specifically for a 'soft' redirection (201 or 202) instead of a Moved Permanently/Found (301/302), so i think that instead of Response.Redirect the conditional line should be:

```
 if(!Request.Url.Host.Equals("www.mywebsite.com"))
 {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("Location", "www.mywebsite.com");
 }
```

EDIT: I believe the status may also be set directly, used in conjunction with Response.Redirect:

```
 if(!Request.Url.Host.Equals("www.mywebsite.com"))
 {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("www.mywebsite.com");
      HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "201 Created";
 }
```

Comment: Thanks that do the trick exactly as I want but do I have to put this piece of code in every action method of all my controllers or can I found a place where I can put it only once and it will control this for all the controllers and actions (such as Global.asax) ?

Comment: There's a few ways to implement this.

On a classic WebForms app, you may create a class that inherits from the base System.Web.UI.Page class, implement this content on the Page_Load event and inherit from this new class instead of System.Web.UI.Page on each new page you create.

You may also implement a HTTP Module to intercept all HTTP requests,  and implement this on a handler for the PostAcquireRequestState event.

Comment: Glad to hear - err, read - that! Feel free to ask in the case you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just add/append header information, then use [Response.AppendHeader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader.aspx).

The Request.Url.ToString() property can be checked for the url you are looking for as per Ryan's answer.

Comment: I'm currently using this snippet :

    if (!Request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("www"))
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://www.mywebsite.com" + Request.RawUrl);
    }

In the Index method of my Home Controller (which is the entry point). But sometimes users arrives on my website through another controller and/or action thus the verification isn't done.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not totally missing something here, can't you just setup the host-header in the IIS settings for the site to include both www.domain.com as well as domain.com?